# SQL to check current date with column of type string which stores date in the format MMDD is not 120 days old

Tags: sql, oracle

Oracle table in my application has a  column with name "transaction_date" of type string. It stores date in the format MMDD, where MM = month and DD = day.

Please help me to write a SQL statement which will compare the transaction_date column with the current system date, if transaction_date is less than or equal to 120 days, then fetch the records from the table.

The problem I am facing is, transaction_date in db does not have year just month and day as a string value, so how to check if that value is not more than 120 days, that check should work if value in column is of previous year. For example, SQL should work for the scenario where current system date is lets say 01 feb 2018, and the transaction_date column in table has value "1225" (25th dec of previous year).

Comment: You should seriously consider storing day, month, and year, ideally in a single _date_ column.  Not storing year is a bad idea, and storing month/day as text is also a bad idea.

Comment: What year do we assume for the data in the `transaction_date` column?

Comment: data in transaction_date  can be of current year or previous year.  I cannot change the current design of db to store year. The table store transaction details and data in the table can be only 6 months old. Any date that is more than 6 months old is automatically deleted from the table by some job

Comment: This is going to be tough to swing.  Honestly, you might find it easier to just store the year in your table.

Comment: I understand your rational to add new column, It makes sense to have new date column, but trying to find out a solution which does not ask for db design change due to some project specific reasons.

Comment: How do you know whether a given `MMDD` belongs to the current year, or the previous year?

Comment: the value of month can only be 6 months old, if we compare it with current month, its going to be fall in the current year or previous year.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182662/discussion-between-reena-upadhyay-and-tim-biegeleisen).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a general disclaimer, your current table design is sub optimal, because a) you are storing dates as text, and b) you are not even storing the year for each date.  From what you wrote, it looks like you want to consider all data as having occurred within the last year, from the current date.

One trick we can try here is to compare the `MMDD` text for each record in your table against `TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MMDD')`, using the following logic:

- If the `MMDD` is *less* than or equal to today, then it gets assigned to current year (2018 as of the time of writing this answer)
- If the `MMDD` is *greater* than today, then it gets assigned to *previous* year (2017).

Then, we may build dates for each record using the appropriate year and check if it is within 120 days of `SYSDATE`.

```
WITH yourTable AS (
    SELECT '0101' AS date_col FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT '1001' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT '1027' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT '1215' FROM dual
)

SELECT
    date_col
FROM yourTable
WHERE
    (date_col <= TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MMDD') AND
     TO_DATE(date_col || TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YYYY'), 'MMDDYYYY') >= SYSDATE - 120) OR
    (date_col > TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'MMDD') AND
     TO_DATE(date_col ||
         TO_CHAR(TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -12), 'YEAR'), 'YYYY'), 'MMDDYYYY') >=
         SYSDATE - 120);
```

### Demo